# Maximum A Poseriori - Regression - Dependence between feature coefficients and features?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, posterior

I was going through some lectures on regression when I came across these statements.

[image]

[image]

Wouldn't the expansions, respectively, be $P(w|y,X) = \frac {P(y|w,X)*P(w|x)}  {P(y|X)} $ and $ P(y,w|X) = P(y|w,X) * P(w|X) $ ?

Or is this because we assume $ P(w|X) = P(w) $, as without a corresponding output, $y$, a set of features, $X$, independently are meaningless ?